# SQL didn't return a row with a column values of NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I just want to exclude the row if the status value is "hidden". But the rows with NULL values is being excluded also. The main objective is to hide only the status if it's hidden.

This is my query:

```
SELECT t.id, t.task_name, t.status, t.assigned_user_task FROM 
`wp_hb_project_tasks` as t
INNER JOIN `wp_hb_projects` as p ON p.id = t.project_id
WHERE p.client_id = '2119' AND t.project_id = 101 AND t.status != "hidden" 
ORDER BY t.created_date DESC
```

The output of the first query is:

[image]

This is my second query removing the "t.status != 'hidden'":

```
SELECT t.id, t.task_name, t.status, t.assigned_user_task FROM 
`wp_hb_project_tasks` as t
INNER JOIN `wp_hb_projects` as p ON p.id = t.project_id
WHERE p.client_id = '2119' AND t.project_id = 101 ORDER BY t.created_date 
DESC
```

The output of the second query:
[image]

I also tried something like t.status != "hidden" AND t.status IS NULL but still I'm not getting the rows with the status of NULL. Am I missing something?

Comment: instead of 'AND', you need 'OR'. See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.task_name, t.status, t.assigned_user_task FROM 
`wp_hb_project_tasks` as t
INNER JOIN `wp_hb_projects` as p ON p.id = t.project_id
WHERE p.client_id = '2119' AND t.project_id = 101 AND (t.status != "hidden" or t.Status is null)
ORDER BY t.created_date DESC
```

Comment: Wow @Gauvarasa. It works. Didn't figure it out! Thanks mate.